# Android: read pdf file

Tags: java, android, listview, pdf, pdfviewer

I want use a PDFViewer in my Android app. In the FirstActivity I load my pdf file in a listview, this is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    private ListView mainListView ;  
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;  

    String filepath;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );  
        final ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();  

        final File storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(storage,"/Folder/");

        if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {
            for (String s : file.list()) {
                sb.append(s + " ");

                List.addAll( Arrays.asList(s) );
            }
        }

        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, R.id.rowTextView,List); 
        mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );  

        mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                String filepath = new File("/Folder/"+ List.get(arg2)).getAbsolutePath();

                openPdfIntent(filepath);


            }


        });
    }
    private void openPdfIntent(String path) {
            try {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The SecondActivity shows pdf file, but I have the error that "file is not found", this is the code:

```
public class SecondActivity extends PdfViewerActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public int getPreviousPageImageResource() {
        return R.drawable.left_arrow;
    }

    public int getNextPageImageResource() {
        return R.drawable.right_arrow;
    }

    public int getZoomInImageResource() {
        return R.drawable.zoom_in;
    }

    public int getZoomOutImageResource() {
        return R.drawable.zoom_out;
    }

    public int getPdfPasswordLayoutResource() {
        return R.layout.pdf_file_password;
    }

    public int getPdfPageNumberResource() {
        return R.layout.dialog_pagenumber;
    }

    public int getPdfPasswordEditField() {
        return R.id.etPassword;
    }

    public int getPdfPasswordOkButton() {
        return R.id.btOK;
    }

    public int getPdfPasswordExitButton() {
        return R.id.btExit;
    }

    public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() {
        return R.id.pagenum_edit;
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If it says file not found, did you investigate what path you're passing to SecondActivity? Is it indeed a valid path or not?

Comment: Android provide built In facility for opening ur pdf stuff .You want to customize it in your own way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in app from your device using following code in your function named openPdfIntent()

Example:

```
public void openPdfIntent(String filePath){
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(filePath);
                    Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                    pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    try {
                        startActivity(pdfIntent);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        UDF.getdialog("You don't have application for PDF Viewer.",
                                activity);
                    }
    }
```

Comment: Uri path = Uri.fromFile(filePath); doesn't want a path but File

Comment: I installed Adobe Acrobat on my phone but it doesn't open my pdf file